# select two cells from table with span class

Tags: html-agility-pack

How can I select two cells in table bases on span class?
my html looks like this.
what I want is to select innertext of span class="store-name-span"
and span class="price"

```
<table class="list mixed zebra-striped">
<tbody>

    <tr data-pris_typ="normal">

        <td class="span4-5">
            <span class="store-name-span">Electroworld</span>
            <a data-drg="store-2641" class="drg-sidebar"></a>
        </td>

        <td class="span3 cell-bar">
            <span class="chart-bar price" style="width:50px"></span>
            <span class="price" title="Uppdaterad 2013-02-18 08:23">1&nbsp;690:-</span>
        </td>

    </tr>
        <tr data-pris_typ="normal">

        <td class="span4-5">
            <span class="store-name-span">Webhallen</span>
            <a data-drg="store-113" class="drg-sidebar"</a>
        </td>


        <td class="span3 cell-bar">
            <span class="chart-bar price" style="width:50px"></span>
            <span class="price" title="Uppdaterad 2013-02-18 13:55">1&nbsp;690:-</span>
        </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

var Nodes = from x in doc2.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                        //where x.Attributes["class"].Value == "store-name-span"
                        where x.Name == "span" && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "store-name-span"
                        select x.InnerText;
```

Comment: var Nodes = from x in doc2.DocumentNode.Descendants()
where x.Name == "span" && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "store-name-span"
select x.InnerText;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that particular HTML layout, you can do:

```
var items = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@data-pris_typ='normal']").Select(x => new
    {
        Store = x.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='store-name-span']").InnerText,
        Price = x.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='price']").InnerText
    });
```

On `items` you'll get what you need. Each item will be an anonymous type with the `Store` and `Price` fields.

**One important thing:**

You might want to clean the fields (like `Price`) using `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`. To do that you will have to add a reference to the `System.Web` assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use xpath for this:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='store-name-span' or @class='price']");
foreach (var node in nodes)
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
```

By using LINQ:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("span")
    .Where(s => 
        s.GetAttributeValue("class", null) == "store-name-span" || 
        s.GetAttributeValue("class", null) == "price"
    );
```

this will get you:

```
Electroworld
1&nbsp;690:-
Webhallen
1&nbsp;690:-
```

Comment: Ok nice but it is possible with linq?
so that I can have a list like price = x, company = y

Comment: @TomasBredh Check my answer for what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector) and fetching innerHTML.

queryselectors work both on calling globally (on document) as well as for a single element.